# Create customized S function blocks and also generate C code using real time workshop for the same

Tags: c, matlab, simulink, s-function, rtw

I want to create customized S function blocks and also generate C code for them using real time workshop. I could not quite find the correct documents for this task. Could someone please help me by pointing to correct and easy documentation?

Comment: They'll have to be C S-functions. Level 1 M S-functions are not supported by code generation. Level 2 M S-functions are supported, but you will need to write the TLC that goes with your S-function. See for example http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/40240-tlc-file-for-level-2-s-function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have Simulink Coder (and its documentation) installed, then for a general discussion of how c-mex S-Functions are handled open the doc by doing

```
docsearch('Insert S-Function Code')
```

then click on the link that says 'Insert S-Function Code' -- which may not be the first link.

To see info on how to inline an S-Function using a .tlc file look at the following,

```
docsearch('Inlining C MEX S-Functions')
```

Comment: Thanks both for your help. I am able do this now. but facing another problem. Do have any idea about concatination of type real_T with string in tlc scripts ?